# add multiple images in a word doc

Tags: php, ms-word, com

I ve got a few images stored in a database along with a type field,lets say its A or B. I am trying to add them to a word template, into fields that i named imgPlaceholder1 and imgPlaceholder2 depending on the type of the image. heres my current code:

```
        $wordTable = new COM("Word.Application") or die("Unable to instanciate Word");
$wordTable->visible = 1;
$wordTable->Documents->Open("c:\template\file.doc");

    try {
        $query = "select id,path,type from uploads Where id = '$Id'";
        $action = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
            while($result = mysql_fetch_array($action)){
                $type=$result['type'];
                $path=$result['path'];
                if($type=='A'){
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->ClearFormatting();
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->Text = 'imgPlaceholder1';
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->Execute();
                    $wordTable->Selection->InlineShapes->AddPicture($path,False,True);  
                }
                if($type=='B'){
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->ClearFormatting();
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->Text = 'imgPlaceholder2';
                    $wordTable->Selection->Find->Execute();
                    $wordTable->Selection->InlineShapes->AddPicture($path,False,True);  
                }
            }
     }
    catch (Exception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

Now, the code works but it does something weird. it ignores the type and pulls everything into the first placeholder. I believe its because of the Selection->Find->Text,but i have no idea how to clear the selection or force it to search something new.
i also tried saving and closing the document, and then inserting the second type of images,but the result is the same. all images end up in the first placeholder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself.
these 3 lines cannot be very far from each other, or they get sad and stop working:

```
$wordTable->Selection->Find->ClearFormatting();
$wordTable->Selection->Find->Text = '_fl_ImgTest_1');
$wordTable->Selection->Find->Execute();
```

then you can get some coding freedom and finally add:

```
$wordTable->Selection->InlineShapes->AddPicture($path,False,True);
```

repeat the procedure with the second string to find,and it will work